# jQuery - List result based on dropdown option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please review my [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/P2LEX/)

If you select an option from a menu, it will match up with another corresponding option.

In the first menu, if you select a type of exam, it will match up with an appropriate course result.

Additionally, the second menu allows you to select a course, and the appropriate exam result will be displayed.

For example - If you select **American Literature** or **Introduction to Educational Psychology**, the result displayed is **Free Elective**

However, if in the menu below, you select **Free Elective**, the only course that comes up is **American Literature**, and not the other **Introduction to Educational Psychology**.

How can I select **Free Elective** and have it display a list of classes associated, and not just one?

**Here is my JS**...

```
$(function() {
    $('#clepSelector').change(function(){
        $('.class').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('#classSelector').change(function(){
        $('.clep').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need 2 separate `$(function () {})` (document.ready's). You can all your event handlers inside one.

Comment: Ok. In combination with Krishna's answer... that's what I needed. Thanks @mcpDESIGNS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you cannot have duplicate IDs in the DOM.

So, remove `free_elective` as an `id` & make it a `class`.

HTML

```
<div class="clep free_elective" style="display: none"> American Literature </div>
<div class="clep free_elective" style="display: none"> Introduction to Educational Psychology </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#classSelector').change(function(){
    $('.clep').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
});
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P2LEX/8/)***